# Companion objects in scala

Tags: scala

can any one explain the following output. I have a simple Scala code like this..

```
object compOrNotTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var emp = new Employee("tom", 20)
    println(emp)
    println(Employee.adult(emp))
    Employee.printName("Roland", 38)

    var emp2 = new Employee("Harry", 37)
    Employee.printName(emp2)
  }
}

class Employee(name: String, age: Int) {
  val ageOfEmplyedd: Int = age
  val nameEmp: String = name

  override def toString() = this.name + " age : " + this.age

  def printName() {
    println("name is in Class " + nameEmp)
  }
}

object Employee {
  def adult(emp: Employee) = {
    if (emp.ageOfEmplyedd > 18)
      true
    else
      false
  }

  def printName(name: String, age: Int) = {
    val emp1 = new Employee(name, age)
    println("Name is : " + emp1.printName())
  }

  def printName(emp1: Employee) = {
    //val emp1 = new Employee(name, age)
    println("Name is :  "+ emp1.printName())
  }
}
```

And the output I am getting is

```
tom age : 20
true
name is in Class Roland
Name is : ()
name is in Class Harry
Name is : ()
```

My question is that why , when I am calling from Companion object I am getting only `Name is : ()`. I am expecting something like `Name is : name is in Class Roland`. Please help me out to understand the how scala works in this case. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you think it should be this output?
Just put it in a piece of paper.
`Employee.printName("Roland",38)` It makes a call to print name, so it does:
`println("Name is : "+emp1.printName())`,
where it executes first `emp1.printName()` which prints "name is in Class Roland"
and then the rest: "Name is : ()".

Comment: ok ok, yes , my bad.... Thanks a lot , some how got confused....

Comment: @Biswajit I am glad I could help. As this question will probably be of no use to stackoveflow community(what are the chance someone else will have the same problem and reach this question? :) ) you can consider removing it.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `Employee.printName` (in class `Employee`) is `Unit`. This is because this function was declared using *procedure syntax* (a function declaration with no `=` sign in it, [which has been *deprecated*](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605) and which will no longer be supported in a future version of *Scala*) that has an associated return type of `Unit`. The `Unit` value that is returned is represented in Scala as `()`.

The following function declarations are equivalent:

```
// Using (soon-to-be-deprecated) procedure syntax.
def printName() {
  println("name is in Class " + nameEmp)
}

// Using an explicit return type.
def printName(): Unit = {
  println("name is in Class " + nameExp)
}

// Using an inferred return type (note "=" in declaration). The last statement is the call
// to println, which returns Unit, so a return type of Unit is inferred.
def printName() = {
  println("name is in Class " + nameExp)
}
```

If you wanted to return the string that was printed, you would need something like this:

```
def printName() = {
  val s = "name is in Class " + nameEmp
  println(s)
  s
}
```

Or, using an explicit return type, instead of inferring it from the last statement:

```
def printName(): String = {
  val s = "name is in Class " + nameEmp
  println(s)
  s
}
```